# GXT Window hides behind iFrame in IE

Tags: gwt, pdf, embedded-resource, gxt

In my GWT application, I have an iFrame embedding a PDF object. The PDF itself is retrieved from a servlet returning it with `application/pdf` as content type. In Chrome, my Popup, which is a GXT Window, shows in front of the embedded pdf just fine.

In IE however, the popup hides behind the embedded PDF, even if I make its z-index the max value for IE.

I have also tried to call the Window's focus method after loading it, and looked into alternatives for iFrame, but it led to nothing.

How do I make sure the popup Window will show in front of the PDF? What's causing the fact that the PDF brutally forces itself to the front in the current situation?

Comment: IE stacks plugins and other native components (e.g. `<select>`) in their own layers. GWT `PopupPanel` has a workaround for this (underlay an iframe behind the popup), and apparently GXT's Windows don't. I reworded your question's title to that effect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and good call. It was my understanding most GXT widgets were additions to the GWT widgets and not replacements. I'll see if I can find more details on what that workaround is/how it works, do you have any leads?

Comment: Hint: search for "iframe shim"

Comment: GXT widgets have the capability of having a shim, but it is only enabled for select browsers (apparently IE6 and gecko 1.8 on mac). Which version of GXT are you using? Which version of IE?

Comment: Newest GXT (3) as well as GWT (2.5) and IE 10. I followed Thomas' lead but found a plethora of far-fetched solutions that seem to break all kinds of standards I may not want to break, or create other problems. I tried to enable shim for all browsers using `GXT.setUseShims(true)`, but that didn't help in any way. Found a Shim class in GXT but no clues on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer has Windowed and Windowless elements - [How the Z-index Attribute Works for HTML Elements](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=http://support.microsoft.com:80/support/kb/articles/q177/3/78.asp&NoWebContent=1). Embedded PDF is displayed using plug-in, so it cannot be behind plain DIV.

You should use the technique when an additional IFRAME is put in front of PDF plug-in, but behind the popup. This effectively will make the popup cover displayed PDF. It seems that GXT itself does not provide such a facility (or it does not work properly). You should probably implement your own popup window by extending the one being used. There you would override `show()` method to create and size additional IFRAME.

A good starting example is the implementation of [PopupImplIE6](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/impl/PopupImplIE6.java) in GWT.